# VSCode editorconfig ij_ style for Java

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, editorconfig

I'm working on a project where the style has been defined in an editorconfig file.

All these roles are prefixed with ij_java. I think these are the IntelliJ specific configs. Can I use these style roles somehow from VSCode?

By default, my VSCode uses the RedHat plugin to deal with the style which can't read this config.

Comment: Java extension uses configurations integrated from eclipse. The style you want to apply to project can be stored in `Settings.json` or do some changes to `formatter.xml`, which you can get from **Command Palette-----Java: Open Java Formatter Settings** .